# Error when re-sizing data in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays that I want to re-size, but I also want to retain the original values.  The code below re-sizes the arrays, but the problem is that it over-writes the original values, as you can see when you look at the output from the

```
print(x) 
print(y)
```

commands at the end of the script.  However, if we comment out the line

```
# NewX,NewY=resize(x,y,xmin=MinRR,xmax=MaxRR,ymin=minLVET,ymax=maxLVET)
```

then the original values of x and y print out properly.  However, if we remove the comment and leave the code as is, then x and y are apparently over-written becaue the

```
print(x) 
print(y)
```

commands then output the values for NewX and NewY, respectively.

My code is below.  ***Can anyone show me how to fix the code below so that x and y retain their original values, and so that NewX and NewY get their newly resized values?***

```
import numpy as np

def GetMinRR(age):
    MaxHR = 208-(0.7*age)
    MinRR = (60/MaxHR)*1000
    return MinRR

def resize(x,y,xmin=0.0,xmax=1.0,ymin=0.0,ymax=1.0):
    # Create local variables
    NewX = x
    NewY = y
    # If the mins are greater than the maxs, then flip them.
    if xmin>xmax: xmin,xmax=xmax,xmin 
    if ymin>ymax: ymin,ymax=ymax,ymin
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    # The rest of the code below re-calculates all the values in x and then in y with these steps:
    #       1.) Subtract the actual minimum of the input x-vector from each value of x
    #       2.) Multiply each resulting value of x by the result of dividing the difference
    #           between the new xmin and xmax by the actual maximum of the input x-vector
    #       3.) Add the new minimum to each value of x
    # Note: I wrote in x-notation, but the identical process is also repeated for y
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    # Subtracts right operand from the left operand and assigns the result to the left operand.
    # Note: c -= a is equivalent to c = c - a
    NewX -= x.min()

    # Multiplies right operand with the left operand and assigns the result to the left operand.
    # Note: c *= a is equivalent to c = c * a
    NewX *= (xmax-xmin)/NewX.max()

    # Adds right operand to the left operand and assigns the result to the left operand.
    # Note: c += a is equivalent to c = c + a
    NewX += xmin

    # Subtracts right operand from the left operand and assigns the result to the left operand.
    # Note: c -= a is equivalent to c = c - a
    NewY -= y.min()

    # Multiplies right operand with the left operand and assigns the result to the left operand.
    # Note: c *= a is equivalent to c = c * a
    NewY *= (ymax-ymin)/NewY.max()

    # Adds right operand to the left operand and assigns the result to the left operand.
    # Note: c += a is equivalent to c = c + a
    NewY += ymin

    return (NewX,NewY)

# Declare raw data for use in creating logistic regression equation
x = np.array([821,576,473,377,326],dtype='float') 
y = np.array([255,235,208,166,157],dtype='float') 

# Call resize() function to re-calculate coordinates that will be used for equation
MinRR=GetMinRR(34)
MaxRR=1200
minLVET=(y[4]/x[4])*MinRR
maxLVET=(y[0]/x[0])*MaxRR
NewX,NewY=resize(x,y,xmin=MinRR,xmax=MaxRR,ymin=minLVET,ymax=maxLVET) 

print 'x is:  ',x 
print 'y is:  ',y
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NewX = x.copy()
NewY = y.copy()
```

numpy arrays also support the `__copy__` interface, and can be copied with the copy module, so this would also work:

```
NewX = copy.copy(x)
NewY = copy.copy(y)
```

If you want to retain the current behaviour of the function as-is, you'd need to replace all occurences of `x` and `y` with `NewX` and `NewY`. If the current behaviour of the function is wrong, you might keep them as they are.

Comment: This works with numpy arrays, but not regular lists.  But it's sure easier to understand than my solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

Make explicit copies of `x` and `y` in `resize`:

```
def resize(...):
    NewX = [t for t in x]
    NewY = [t for t in y]
```

Python always passes by reference, so any changes you make in subroutines are made to the actual passed objects.

Answer (score 0):

The original `resize` repeats itself. Everything that is done for x it repeats for y. [That's not good](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), because it means you have to maintain twice as much code as you really need. The solution is to make `resize` work on just one array, and call it twice (or as needed):

```
def resize(arr,lower=0.0,upper=1.0):
    # Create local variables
    result = arr.copy()
    # If the mins are greater than the maxs, then flip them.
    if lower>upper: lower,upper=upper,lower 
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    # The rest of the code below re-calculates all the values in x and then in y with these steps:
    #       1.) Subtract the actual minimum of the input x-vector from each value of x
    #       2.) Multiply each resulting value of x by the result of dividing the difference
    #           between the new lower and upper by the actual maximum of the input x-vector
    #       3.) Add the new minimum to each value of x
    # Note: I wrote in x-notation, but the identical process is also repeated for y
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    # Subtracts right operand from the left operand and assigns the result to the left operand.
    # Note: c -= a is equivalent to c = c - a
    result -= result.min()

    # Multiplies right operand with the left operand and assigns the result to the left operand.
    # Note: c *= a is equivalent to c = c * a
    result *= (upper-lower)/result.max()

    # Adds right operand to the left operand and assigns the result to the left operand.
    # Note: c += a is equivalent to c = c + a
    result += lower
    return result
```

Call it like this:

```
NewX=resize(x,lower=MinRR,upper=MaxRR)
NewY=resize(y,lower=minLVET,upper=maxLVET)
```